# Retrieve the documents from Multiple Attachment Control of Nintex Form

Tags: 2013, list, attachments, nintex

I have a list with the form customized using Nintex.

In that, we have used the multiple attachment control feature of Nintex. Now, I want to retrieve the attachments programmatically.

I can get the list attachments directly but I need the relation with each attachment control.

How can I get the relation of each attachment with its attachment control?

Thanks in Advance.